# how to create a 2D map from laser scan data

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I'm new to ROS. I'm using ROS INDIGO and kinect for my project.I want to create a map from the laser scan data without having odometry data .I converted the depth image to laser scan data.Then how can I create a map using Gmapping for the hand held kinect using this laser scan data?

edited question.
i used hectorslam and there is some problem with tf.
using `rosrun tf view_frames` i got
[image: image description]
and this is my laaunch file for depthimage_to_laserscan `kinect.launch`

---

```
<launch>

<node name="depthimage_to_laserscan" pkg="depthimage_to_laserscan" type="depthimage_to_laserscan">

<remap from="image" to="/camera/depth_registered/image_raw"/>

</node>

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224916/how-to-create-a-2d-map-from-laser-scan-data/) by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2016-01-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying looking into [hector_mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping).  It will build you a map from laser scans and doesn't require odometry data.

---

Originally posted by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) with karma: 258 on 2016-01-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on 2016-01-24**:
thank you sir...it worked for me.Is there any other method using gmapping to do the same.?I read that there is another method using gmapping with laser_scan_matcher. I tried to install it but i was not able to do that.Could you please help me to install this package?

**Comment by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on 2016-01-24**:
I'm not sure.  If you couldn't get laser_scan_matcher to install I would try asking a question with the problem.

**Comment by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on 2016-02-03**:
Hi sir,i am able to get a 2d map with hectorslam using turtlebot package.But now when i am doing it with real kinect I'am getting an error` "[ WARN] [1453709644.419967908]: No transform between frames /map and scanmatcher_frame available after 20.001889 seconds of waiting."'sir please help.

**Comment by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on 2016-02-03**:
Sounds like your missing a transform in your tf data.  Check the required transforms for the nodes your running.  You can look at a pdf of your tf tree with:  rosrun tf view_frames

**Comment by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on 2016-02-05**:
edited previous question

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-02-14**:
Check this out David: http://answers.ros.org/question/208584/hector-slam-does-not-work

**Comment by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on 2016-02-15**:
did it like this,but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can either use hector_mapping, as jseal suggested, or a combination of [laser_scan_matcher](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher) and slam_gmapping (or even slam_karto). You'll first need to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-scan-tools
```

Then, here's an excerpt of how you'd run it from a launch file in order to "fake" odometry:

```
<node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node"
  name="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen">

  <param name="fixed_frame" value="odom"/>
  <param name="use_imu" value="false" type="bool"/>
  <param name="use_odom" value="false" type="bool"/>
  <param name="max_iterations" value="10"/>
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-02-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on 2016-02-15**:
did like this also...but there is nothing uder the topic /map.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-02-15**:
Did you launch slam_gmapping in addition to the laser_scan_matcher and a transform between your base_link and your laser?

**Comment by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on 2016-02-15**:
i lauched slam_gmapping and laser_scan_matcher.........but i didn't do that transform part.could you please help me to do that part.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-02-15**:
You need a transform between the base_link frame and your laser frame (camera_link in your case). Assuming the camera is fixed to the base, you'd add something like:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser"
  args="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 /base_link /camera_link 50" />
```